# Cat behavior towards new cat

Tags: cats

We got a new cat a week ago. Tbh we did not do a slow introduction. my old cat was super excited and curious but the new cat seems to like to mind his business. They are both 1 years old. At first the new cat was slapping first but now the old cat seems to gotten use to it and started to slap him out of no where and showing signs of dominance. here is my concern, my old cat likes to follow my new cat everywhere. and will not leave his side. They rough house sometimes and when my new cat hissed I will separate them. I feel like my new cat can’t enjoy his new environment with my old cat around. He will only cuddle with me and wants to be pet when my old cat is not around. How can I get my old cat to just leave my new cat alone? Or does he really want to be friends with the new guy? I know for a fact that the new cat has not open up to him but we have a cat tree that is pretty vertical so the new cat will sleep in the tree and my old cat will sleep near him in the tree as well.

Comment: There are positive interactions sometimes; they have sniffed noses and I’ve seen my new cat grooming my old cat when he’s trying to dominate him. My older cat has sniffed the new cat butthole a couple of times and I’ve only seen my new cat sniffing him once.

Comment: Welcome to pets.SE! We have a lots of questions about new cats and old cats. Did you use the search function? Are the cats spayed/neutered?

Comment: What you describe is stalking and your old cat trying to intimidate this stranger, who invaded his territory. If you already know about the slow introduction, you should do it before the simmering conflict escalates. Also make sure each cat has his own toilet, food and water bowl and safe place to sleep to avoid conflict over resources.